# Signup Form that adds customer to MailChimp, redirects to checkout, and fills in form data

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms, plugin-mailchimp

You can see what I am trying to do on [this test page](https://moneyballerz.com/homepagee/) - the top button labelled "MAILCHIMP + CHECKOUT" is what I'm working on.

I am trying to accomplish 3 things (at the moment 2 & 3 are working on my test page):

1. Send form data to MailChimp
2. Redirect to checkout
3. Auto-populate the checkout fields with the form data

I can use a plugin and make a form that sends data to MailChimp that works fine, but when I add code to do 2 & 3 the MailChimp plugin fails. The plugin I'm using is [MailChimp for WordPress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/) and the form I made with it is structured like this:

```
<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" placeholder="First Name"
    required="">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="LNAME" placeholder="Last Name"
    required="">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input type="tel" name="PHONE" placeholder="Phone" required="">
</p>
<p>
    <label>Email address: 
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" placeholder="Email" required />
</label>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Give me 2 Weeks FREE" onclick=""/>
</p>
```

The code I'm using to accomplish 2 & 3 is here:

```
<script>
    var regForm1 = jQuery('#mc4wp-form-1'),
         regBtn1 = jQuery('#mc4wp-form-1 input[type=submit]');

    regBtn1.on('click touch', function(e1) {
        e1.preventDefault();

        billing_first_name = regForm1.find('.mc4wp-form-fields > p:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(2)').val()
         billing_last_name = regForm1.find('.mc4wp-form-fields > p:nth-child(2) > input:nth-child(2)').val()
                     billing_phone = regForm1.find('.mc4wp-form-fields > p:nth-child(3) > input:nth-child(2)').val()           
             billing_email = regForm1.find('.mc4wp-form-fields > p:nth-child(4) > label:nth-child(1) > input:nth-child(1)').val()
                
        // Add Cookies
         if (billing_first_name && billing_last_name && billing_phone && billing_email) {

              alert(billing_first_name + " - " + billing_last_name + " - " + billing_phone + " - " + billing_email);

            Cookies.set("billing_first_name", billing_first_name, {
               path: '/',
               expiration: 30
            })
            Cookies.set("billing_last_name", billing_last_name, {
               path: '/',
               expiration: 30
            })
            Cookies.set("billing_phone", billing_phone, {
                path: '/',
                expiration: 30
            })
            Cookies.set("billing_email", billing_email, {
                path: '/',
                expiration: 30
            })
            
            var url = `?add-to-cart=18074`;
            alert(url);
            window.location = url; 
            } else {
                alert("Please fill in all fields");
            }
        });
    // Fill in the cookies and immediately remove
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            const billing_first_name = Cookies.get("billing_first_name");
            const billing_last_name = Cookies.get("billing_last_name");
            const billing_email = Cookies.get("billing_email");
            const billing_phone = Cookies.get("billing_phone");

        if (billing_first_name) {
            $("#billing_first_name").val(billing_first_name)
            Cookies.remove("billing_first_name")
        }
        if (billing_last_name) {
            $("#billing_last_name").val(billing_last_name)
            Cookies.remove("billing_last_name")
        }
        if (billing_phone) {
            $("#billing_phone").val(billing_phone)
            Cookies.remove("billing_phone")
        }
        if (billing_email) {
            $("#billing_email").val(billing_email)
            Cookies.remove("billing_email")
        }
    })
    })(jQuery)
    
</script>
```

Any ideas on how I could make this work? Do I need to make something wait for something or do I need an entirely new approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got help with this, the fix involved two functions in functions.php and one plugin.

The functions:

```
// Add to Cart for optin Form

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'website_add_to_cart_on_custom_page');
 
function website_add_to_cart_on_custom_page(){
 
    if( is_page( 'homepagee' ) ) { // is a page slug
 
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( 18074 ); // add to cart product with ID
 
    }
 
}


// Autofill checkout fields from URL
 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'website_prefill_checkout_fields');
  
function website_prefill_checkout_fields ( $checkout_fields ) {
  
    /**
     * Query string fields to populate in checkout,
     *
     * Ex.
     * 'fname' => is query parameter name,
     * 'billing_first_name' => matching field of checkout 
     *
     * You can add other fields in the same way
     */
    $query_fields = array(
         
        'fname' => 'billing_first_name',
        'lname' => 'billing_last_name',
        'email' => 'billing_email',
        'phone' => 'billing_phone',
    );
 
    // We will loop the above array to check if the field exists in URL or not.
    // If it exists we will add it to the checkout field's default value
 
    foreach ( $query_fields as $field_slug => $match_field ) {
         
        // Check if it is in URL or not, An not empty.
        if ( isset( $_GET[ $field_slug ] ) && ! empty( $_GET[ $field_slug ] ) ) {
 
            // Sanitize the value and store it in a variable.
            $field_value = sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ $field_slug ] );
 
            // Check if match field exists in checkout form or not.
            if( isset( $checkout_fields['billing'][ $match_field ] ) ){
 
                // Assign the pre-fill value to checkout field
                $checkout_fields['billing'][ $match_field ]['default'] = $field_value;
            }
        }       
    }
 
 
    // Return the fields
    return $checkout_fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_login_form', 10 );
```

The plugin we used was https://wordpress.org/plugins/mailchimp-for-wp/ and under the Form > Form Behaviour in this section we selected 'Yes' for the "Hide form after a successful sign-up?" and then added a url in the "Redirect to URL after successful sign-ups" field.

In that field, we followed the following format:

```
https://domain.com/checkout/?fname={data key="FNAME"}&lname={data key="LNAME"}&email={data key="EMAIL"}&phone={data key="PHONE"}
```

Hopefully this helps someone down the road.